# Why isn't 'npm install -g @angular/cli' installing on visual studio code terminal?

Tags: angular, installation, terminal

As I watched many vidoes trying to install Angular on Visual Studio Code with npm install -g @angular/cli but with every attempt, there was an npm error meaning the installation has failed. Has anyone expeirence the same issue and would appreciate how to fix this error?

[Trying to install in Visual Studio code terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Qyuc.png)

[The errors shown in terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y57i0.png)

Comment: By reading your error, it seems it's a problem of access rights.
Can you try to run the command with admin privilege ?
`sudo npm install -g @angular/cli` if you are on a unix system.

Comment: Have you tried using the --force command already as suggested in the prompts?

Comment: Valentin Roche- Sudo is not recognized in the command

Comment: Desmond- I had tried --force command and nothing changed

Comment: Check if opening VS Code as admin helps

Comment: @MathewHo So you are saying --force also gave same error output? Try what Benny has suggested above. Otherwise you can go to you npm directory as given in your screenshot delete ng file and try installing then